# Unmarshal vs Json.parse in scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to scala and the play framework and am looking to convert Json to scala object. I came across two solutions

```
Unmarshal(response.entity).to[JsValue]
```

and

```
Json.parse(response.entity)
```

Is there a difference and if yes - when should i be using `unmarshal` vs `json.parse`.

Comment: What are the two json parsing libraries that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should perform unmarshalling when you know the number of arguments prior to deserialization(especially mapping directly to a case class).

The other approach is preferred when specific parameters need to be fetched from a response schema that is not known before or that changes frequently.

Let me know if it helps!!